# Accessing inner class reference from outer class

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Why is that a reference to inner class can be accessed while it is declared in outer class by the outer class whereas it cannot be accessed while it is declared inside the inner class ?

In the below code I declared head as a reference inside the inner class which I tried to access from outer class but I cannot able to. If I declare the same reference in outer class it works fine. Why is that so ?

```
public class QueueUsingLL {
    public void additem(int n)
    {
        node nw = new node(n,head);
    if(head == null)
{
    head = nw;
}
else
{
    nw.next = head;
    head =nw;

}   
    }
public class node
{
    int item;
    node next;
    node head= null;    
    node(int item,node next)
            {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;

            }

}
```

Comment: Have a look on this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @rajmohanloganathan use Camel Case while defining class. Like `public class Node`

Comment: @Rahul: I cannot find much in that page regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `head` is initialized with `null`, at the moment of creating a new `node` you can pass `null` to the `next` parameter:

```
public void additem(int n)
{
    node nw = new node(n, null); 
}
```

**Why you can't access `head`?**

Because `head` is a member of the class `node`, so you first need to create an instance of that class to access it.

**Recommendation:**

As @Qadir said, use CamelCase names for classes, this is a Java convention, and helps to distinct between classes and fields.

Comment: I have created an instance inside the node class.
This code is working if I declare node head = null; in the outer class. why is it so ?

Comment: When you have a class, let's say `Node`, to access a field of that class (not declared as static) you must create an instance of the class `Node`, something like `Node n1 = new Node(...)` so you can acess its field as `n1.head`. When you declare `node head = null` in the outer class, when you create an instance of the class `node` in `node nw = new node(n, head)`, you can access `head` because it is already defined within the scope of the outer class.